# React js image not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the directory:

[image]

```
import {useRef} from "react"
import {FaBars, FaTimes} from "react-icons/fa"
import "../css/navbar.css"

export function Navbar() {
    const navRef = useRef()

    const showNavBar = () => {
        navRef.current.classList.toggle("responsive-nav");
    }

    return (
        <navbar>
            <img src="my-app/public/images/logos/word logo trans-preview.png" />
            <nav ref={navRef}>
                <a href="/#">Home</a>
                <a href="/#">Services</a>
                <a href="/#">About</a>
                <a href="/#" className="bottom">Contact</a>
                <button className="nav-btn nav-close-btn" onClick={showNavBar}>
                    <FaTimes/>
                </button>
            </nav>
            <button className="nav-btn" onClick={showNavBar}>
                <FaBars/>
            </button>
        </navbar>
    )
}
```

the file location is correct and the code should be correct. Why isn't it loading? everything else is working fine...

I tried moving it to different folders, I tried getting a new pc, I moved homes... Please i need help :(

Comment: React is a UI framework and isn't related to how your server serves images. It depends on what server you're using. You probably want to remove `my-app/public/` and make it `/images/...`.

Comment: Remove these white spaces in the filename `word logo trans-preview.png`. Try to add a hyphen like this `word-logo-trans-preview.png` and use relative paths `../../` adjust your relative path to your needs.

Comment: @Quimbo no. spaces in filenames are fine.

Comment: spaces are not recommended in file names, as they may cause issues with some browsers or servers. It is better to use hyphens or underscores instead of spaces, as they are more compatible and readable. - @AndyRay

Comment: @VictorL. spaces in the filename is not related to the question/issue in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, you can get the image path in `public` directory directly.
Also, you need to use hyphens or underscores instead of spaces because they may cause problems with loading the image.

For example:

```
<img src="/images/logos/word-logo-trans-preview.png" />
```

instead of:

```
<img src="my-app/public/images/logos/word logo trans-preview.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just import that image into the current file and use it

```
import logo from "path to your image"


<img src={logo}>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to rename your image and remove the white space in the image name from `word logo trans-preview.png` to something like `word-logo-trans-preview.png` or any other names as long as there is no white space between the words.

Method 1.
You can update your JSX to look like

```
<img src="/images/logos/word-logo-trans-preview.png" />
```

Method 2.
Import the image just like any other javascript files

```
import logo from "../some-path-to-the-image/word-logo-trans-preview.png"
```

then in your JSX

```
    <img src={logo} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got a couple of tries for you!

First of all, have you tried escaping the spaces in the file name?

```html
<img src="my-app/public/images/logos/word\ logo\ trans-preview.png" />
```

Anyway, is a good practice **not having spaces in filenames.**

Second option:
have you tried importing your image in React Way?

```js
import transPreview from "../../public/images/logos/word\ logo\ trans-preview.png"
```

and then in your image you can do like:

```html
<img src={transPreview} alt="transPreview">
```

In both scenarios, I suggest you to replaces the spaces in the filename with _ or -.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

From an url you can access to the public folder directly on the root of your domain name `http://localhost:3000/` for example.

So if you want to access to `my-app/public/images/my-image.png`, use the following path :

```
<img src={'/images/my-image.png'} />
```

You can also have an issue with space in your path. I advise you to use the function `encodeURI` to encode all special characters to make it understandable in your url. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```
<img src={encodeURI("/images/logos/word logo trans-preview.png")} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).